# How can a javascript function, called with single argument, can call function with varying arguments?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a php application, in which I have the following existing code:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#" id="BillingP" onClick="change_main_Selection(this);">Paper</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" id="BillingE" onClick="change_main_Selection(this);">Electronic</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" id="BillingE" onClick="change_main_Selection(this,'CLHReports');">Clearing House Reports</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" id="BillingCP" onClick="change_main_Selection(this);">Capitation</a></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see function change_main_Selection(this) gets called, when user clicks on tab. I have tried to find change_main_Selection() definition and found following:

```
function change_main_Selection(main_tab, sub_tab, redirect_url, flgNc, onload){
    var main_tab_obj = main_tab;
    var sub_tab_obj = sub_tab;
}
```

My confusion is that while calling change_main_Selection(), it only takes single argument. But how can it call change_main_Selection() function with multiple arguments.

Comment: Not passed arguments consider as `undefined`. Read language docs.

Comment: Note that you can also call a function with *more* arguments than it explicitly defines.

Answer (score 2):

A JavaScript function does not perform any checking on parameter values (arguments).

If a function is called with missing arguments (less than declared), the missing values are set to: `undefined`

Sometimes this is acceptable, but sometimes it is better to assign a default value to the parameter:

```
function myFunction(x, y) {
    y = y || 'defaultValue'; // overwrites falsey values (0, null, false)

    // better approach
    if (typeof y === 'undefined') { y = 'defaultValue'; }
}
```

With ES6, you can provide default values in a C++ style default values as follows:

```
function myFunction(x, y='defaultValue'){}
```

Comment: Note that using `||` will overwrite actual *defined* values if they are falsey.

Comment: Something like `if (typeof y === 'undefined') { y = 'defaultValue'; }` would be better

Comment: Yes true guys, this covers better range of cases

Answer (score 1):

Javascript functions are called `variadic` functions. You can pass `less params` or `more params`. When you pass less params, extra params are set to `undefined`. If you pass more, you can see them in a special array like object called `arguments`.

See below example when you pass more arguments.

```
function sum() {
var s = 0;  
for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){
        s+= arguments[i];
}
return s;
}

var ans = sum(1,2,3);
console.log(ans);//6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access to arguments by `arguments` variable inside your function as explained in [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp) this means there is no need to declare any parameter explicitly in your function:

```js
x = findMax(1, 123, 500, 115, 44, 88);
console.info(x);
function findMax() {
  var i;
  var max = -Infinity;
  for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    if (arguments[i] > max) {
      max = arguments[i];
    }
  }
  return max;
}
```

and you can access them by `arguments` variable